# HTML5 compliant html page

Tags: html, jslint

What does it mean to say the html page is HTML5 complaint or not? As a team leader, I need to come up with the check points to validate if the templates or pages designed and developed conform to the HTML standards and semantics, so that I can document it and socialize it within the team.

I know there are HTML5 linting tools available on web, but I want to know what standards have to be checked for HTML5 specifications.

Thanks,
Mandar.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're actually asking. To be HTML5 compliant, a page must comply to the HTML5 specification. The specification is the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandar, that's not really an easy question to answer.

Are you talking about just HTML markup?
If that's the case, then practically any valid html4.01 is going to be valid html5, once you change `<!doctype html>`.

...but that's not really saying a lot, and it's not really adding anything new.  ...are you using html5 elements, like `<article>`?
If so, are you planning on supporting old browsers?
Then you'll need to include the html5 shim JS file...

But that's not something that an HTML5 validator will tell you.

Knowing where a `pubdate` attribute in a `<time>` element does and doesn't belong is also something that a validator won't tell you.

At the most basic level, read some tutorials on making an HTML5-compatible blog.
There were a lot of those written in 2009/2010.

Or you might also look at Introducing HTML5 second edition by Remy Sharp and Bruce Lawson.

If all you want to do is have it validate, then write XHTML or HTML4 and change your doctype.
If you want to learn how much cleaner html5 can be, then there are literally hundreds of places you can look, and I'd recommend starting with those and HTML5 doctor, and using Mozilla Developer Network to brush up on modern JavaScript features/DOM APIs/"html5" APIs.

Comment: FYI - the pubdate attribute is no longer part of the <time> element.

Comment: I had thought it had stayed a part of the WHATWG-spec. That said, I can't find it anywhere. Hooray for keeping tabs on things. PS: @IanDevlin, thanks for the hard work you had put in, to try to get it back in W3C. I don't want to use hAtom or vCard or anything of the sort, aside from schema.org microdata, which Google, Bing and Yahoo will all support.  ...and as `<time>` is supported, how useful would it be for Google to instantly know which time is applicable to an event, versus the article published about it? I guess there's always HTML5.2...

Answer (score 1):

probably this may help, http://validator.nu/ .you can select the "textfield" in the drop down and drop your html5 code in there and  In the preset and parser you can select the HTML5 version and it will check for the HTML5 standards . it show you the errors if any for the version you selected. this is just an example there are other validators you can use but to understand the standards probably the Books mentioned above will help.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it was really heplful. One thing I was pondering over is, can we use the http://validator.nu/ or other linting site's web service and prepare a tool to integrate in the IDE or source control, so that the html 5 conformance can be enforced?

Comment: The problem with using the w3c validator is that the proprietary data/markup is sent to a third-party server, which is unreliable.

Comment: I have prepared an app which gets all the HTML5 pages from the application and opens it in Visual Studio editor, in VSTS, you have the option to check HTML5 compliant tags as part of the Web Essentials.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at HTML5 specifications..
[W3Schools HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp)

There you can have details of HTML5.

Though this question probably not fits Stackoverflow's Q&A format.. It will lead to an essay or book and it is beyond the scope defined in the FAQ.

Thanks

Comment: You've made more of a comment... than an answer.

Comment: I was below 50 when I made that answer.. so, comment option was not open to me then

Comment: Note that [w3schools](http://w3fools.com) is not W3C. Your link does not point to actual HTML5 specifications.

Comment: I know that... I don't think pointing him to W3C is a good idea.. chances are he'll not get much of the things.. and my links contain a pointer to HTML5 tutorial.

Comment: You're assuming the OP is a complete newbie and unfamiliar with HTML5. If he's a design team leader I surely hope that's not the case.

Comment: Perhaps he is? I can't assume anything... and moreover, getting startup kits are always useful..

Comment: I have prepared an app which gets all the HTML5 pages from the application and opens it in Visual Studio editor, in VSTS, you have the option to check HTML5 compliant tags as part of the Web Essentials.